# checking for empty or whitespaces input text box JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, null, whitespace, string

I'm having web seminars for learning JS and we 're asked to create a simple Form. Now we need to check if an input text-box is empty or it has only white spaces.

Here is the Lab Solution:

```
if (firstTextBoxContent != "" && firstTextBoxContent != null)
```

while this is the solution it worked for me:

```
if (/\S/.test(firstTextBoxContent))
```

Is my way good enough to stick with it and why Tutor's way didn't work at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lab solution is bad, as it first checks if firstTextBoxContent is empty, and then checks if it is null/undefined.
If it is undefined, the first check will result in a reference error and should therefore be in the reverse order.
However, the lab solution doesn't check for whitespaces.
Your solution won't work if firstTextBoxContent is undefined, so if there's a possibility for that, make sure to check like so:

```
 firstTextBoxContent != null && /\S/.test(firstTextBoxContent)
```

some tests:

```
> firstTextBoxContent = undefined
>  firstTextBoxContent != null && /\S/.test(firstTextBoxContent)
false
> firstTextBoxContent = null
>  firstTextBoxContent != null && /\S/.test(firstTextBoxContent)
false
> firstTextBoxContent = ''
>  firstTextBoxContent != null && /\S/.test(firstTextBoxContent)
false
> firstTextBoxContent = ' '
>  firstTextBoxContent != null && /\S/.test(firstTextBoxContent)
false

> firstTextBoxContent = ' b'
>  firstTextBoxContent != null && /\S/.test(firstTextBoxContent)
true
```

---

Another way to do this is

```
 firstTextBoxContent != null && firstTextBoxContent.trim() !== ''
```

to avoid this wisdom:

> You have a problem. You try to solve it with regex. Now you have two problems.

Comment: You've made it pretty clear to me and i think i'd stick with trim() method than the Regex solution.